# How to pass variable in like clause of wmic process?

Tags: batch-file, wmic

I am writing a batch file to kill a process whose commandline arg matches my search criteria
In my batch file:

1) I will take an input from user :

```
 set /p process=Process to Kill:
```

2) Now I will kill all process whose command line matches this parameter

```
WMIC PROCESS WHERE "COMMANDLINE LIKE '%%process%%'" call terminate
```

But this is not working.
By working I mean the matching for like is being performed for `%process%` and not for the value of the process.

So how can I pass the variable in the like clause of CommandLine

Comment: How is it "not working"? Please don't comment, [edit] your question instead!

Answer (score 2):

This example is specific to use from a batch file:

```bat
@Echo Off

:GetProcess
Set "_process="
Set /P "_process=Process to Kill: "
If Not Defined _process GoTo GetProcess

WMIC Process Where "CommandLine Like '%%%_process%%%'" Call Terminate >Nul 2>&1
```

Comment: Absolutely right. Thanks man. So the basic point is to use `%%%` the first % is for the like command and the second `%` is to escape the third `%` …

Comment: No @AkhilSoni, the `Like` operator requires one **`%`**, however, as it is a special character, it should be doubled when used from a batch file, _the first effectively acting as an escape character for the second_. Therefore the `Like` operator from a batch file requires two `%`'s; the variable, `%_process%` remains the same.